# Is 'the dead' a synecdoche?

Tags: rhetoric, rhetorical-devices, synecdoche

Is the phrase 'the dead' a synecdoche? In using it, the individuals are being collectively defined by the fact they are dead, rather than acknowledging their personhood. If it is not a synecdoche, is there another rhetorical trope which it can be classified as?

Thanks

Comment: Relevant: [accurate defintion for poetic devices](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170497/accurate-definition-for-poetic-devices/170537#170537)

Comment: Not much use, I know, but grammatically, "the dead" is a fused-head noun phrase, where the adjective "dead" combines the function of head with that of modifier. We understand it to mean "the dead people".

Answer (score 3):

Whether personhood remains after death is a matter of theology, not rhetoric. In grammatical terms, it's a substantive adjective, that is, an adjective transformed into a noun. Past participles can be substantivized as well. Examples: the poor, the downtrodden, the wealthy, the sick, the homeless... Again, if one feels this usage robs people of their personhood, it still doesn't push this usage into a classical rhetorical term.

Comment: Don't forget active participles too.  They're all noun phrases with an elided noun, which is "ones" (although that itself has an elision of "people" or "things").

Comment: Without challenging the grammar issue here, I am slightly troubled by your suggestion that "whether personhood remains after death is a matter of theology". I would have thought that even the most confirmed atheist would accept that a dead individual's persona survived him or her in the memory of those living, and after that in the historical record.